# Do we have Cloud Page Reporting in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, google-analytics

we have built a Cloud Page as a registration Form and would like to get some reporting on it. OTB i see we have one in reports but it just provides aggregate views but nothing major.Does Google Analytics provide anything( we do not have GA360 but just the free account in MC but we have GA4 )

Any Input would be appreciated. I have gone through articles but all talk about GA 360 but nothing for free account

Answer (score 1):

You can use GA on Cloud Pages as you would on any other site, simply by integrating it directly or via Google Tag Manager.

The data will not flow into SFMC, but why should it? You will still be able to report on the standard metrics within GA, like traffic sources, conversions, etc.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Post integration, I see the links when redirected to the website having UTM parameters. So would they be able to see the traffic in GA4? Also, what standard metrics can GA4 view ? In Journey Analytics , i do not see any numbers showing up. How can the metrics populate on the Journey Analytics dashboard in Journey Builder?